# Why does JavaFX TextFlow not wrap when an unrelated component is aligned BASELINE_LEFT?

Tags: java, javafx, alignment, width

So, this is odd.

My FXML looks like this:

(`RichText` basically just extends `TextFlow` and adds some convenience methods, so it can be considered identical to `TextFlow`.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Border?>

<?import org.trypticon.prototype.RichText?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="org.trypticon.prototype.ListEntryCellController"
      spacing="12">
    <ImageView fx:id="accountIcon" fitWidth="48" fitHeight="48"/>
    <BorderPane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
        <top>
            <HBox alignment="BASELINE_LEFT">
                <RichText fx:id="accountDisplayName" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="15"/>
                    </font>
                </RichText>
                <!-- todo ellipsis for account names but not time -->
                <Text fx:id="statusTime" opacity="0.5" textAlignment="RIGHT">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="15"/>
                    </font>
                </Text>
            </HBox>
        </top>
        <center>
            <RichText fx:id="content">
                <font>
                    <Font size="15"/>
                </font>
                <padding>
                    <Insets top="8" bottom="8"/>
                </padding>
            </RichText>
        </center>
        <bottom>
            <HBox> <!-- Makes buttons align to the left -->
                <ButtonBar>
                    <buttons>
                        <!-- TODO: Wait, what about localisation? -->
                        <Button fx:id="reply" text="Reply" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;"/>
                        <ToggleButton fx:id="reblog" text="Reblog" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;"/>
                        <ToggleButton fx:id="favourite" text="Favourite" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;"/>
                    </buttons>
                </ButtonBar>
            </HBox>
        </bottom>
    </BorderPane>
</HBox>
```

This is rendered inside a `ListCell` such that the width is constrained to the width of the list. But when I render it, the component in the `<center>` smashes the cell out to the right, so that I can't see the other components:

[image: screenshot]

What's odd is, if I remove the `alignment="BASELINE_LEFT"` from the `<top>` component, suddenly the `<center>` component wraps correctly.

For one thing, the top component shouldn't even affect the centre component. But even if it did, merely setting the *alignment* of a component *surely* shouldn't affect the *layout* of an unrelated component?

What is going on here, and how do I avoid it?

I *do* want baseline alignment for the top two text areas, because it's important to lay out text by the baseline. I'm actually not sure why JavaFX didn't make this the default. It's 2017, and I thought we had all learned how to align components correctly by now, but apparently JavaFX's developers haven't.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set max width to your textflow and other objects in textflow

also need to 
`setWrapText(true);` to every views inside your textflow